# Joomla 3 Article Options - How to get article view different from category blog view

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a clean install of Joomla 3.2.3 using the default template and testing with it. Here is how I have it set up at the moment:

```
    Main Menu with Article >> Category Blog
    Main Article category
    4 Test articles linked to the Main Article category
```

I would like to hide the article author (article options) in the category blog view, but when I click to read the full article I would like to have the article author displayed.

When I hide the author in the category blog settings, it also hides the author in the full article view. I can an override this for each article, but this is extremely annoying and might be missed if I forget. From what I understand from googling this is how Joomla propagates these settings (Global -> Menu -> Article). I might be wrong.

Is there a way around this? Custom article view? IMO this is a restrictive design pattern from Joomla, but they might have their reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are always tradeoffs to how settings work, It would be perhaps more annoying if the settings did not follow the menu-setting, but this is what you wanted.

The solution is to override the article content layout. There are a number of articles about this om (eg [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides))

Basically you copy the file components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php to the html/com_content/article - folder of your template, and give it a new name (eg. showauthor.php).  You will also have to override the category blog view in the same way. There you change the article-link so it includes layout=showauthor. This should display the article using the showauthor.php - layout.

regards Jonas

Comment: I would then suggest Joomla add another option "Use Parent" as part of the setting options. I don't know if this would increase complexity, but would definitely improve customization.

Secondly I think in my situation I would rather override the default.php in the article component (don't know if that is bad practice), but I need to get the global and article options from the API. Still browsing the API, haven't found anythig yet.

Comment: I cant think of any reason it should be bad practice to override default.php

Comment: However, I dont think a Use Parent option is very useful. Either this would apply to all options, which might not be what you want after all, or you would need a Use parent-checkbox for every option. And you would still have to set this in every article.